# Python Quadratic Formula Not Calculating Accurately

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

This is my main file that runs program:

```
import math
import Disc

def main():

    coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))
    coeffB = int(input('Enter the coefficient B: '))
    coeffC = int(input('Enter the coefficient C: '))

    disc = Disc.discriminant(coeffA, coeffB, coeffC)

    while coeffA != 0:


        if disc > 0:

            solutionOne = (-coeffB + math.sqrt(disc)) / (2 * coeffA)
            solutionTwo = (-coeffB - math.sqrt(disc)) / (2 * coeffA)

            print('Solutions are: ' + str(solutionOne) + ' and ' + str(solutionTwo))

            coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))
            coeffB = int(input('Enter the coefficient B: '))
            coeffC = int(input('Enter the coefficient C: '))

        elif disc == 0:

            solutionOne = -coeffB / (2 * coeffA)

            print('Solution is: ' + str(solutionOne))

            coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))
            coeffB = int(input('Enter the coefficient B: '))
            coeffC = int(input('Enter the coefficient C: '))

        elif disc < 0:

            print('Equation has two complex roots.')

            coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))
            coeffB = int(input('Enter the coefficient B: '))
            coeffC = int(input('Enter the coefficient C: '))

    else:
        print('Program ended.')


# End of the main function

main()
```

Here is the Disc.py file where the discriminant value is calculated to be used in main() function:

```
def discriminant(coeffA, coeffB, coeffC):

    value = (coeffB ** 2) - (4 * coeffA * coeffC)

    return value
```

This is the output when running the program:

```
Enter the coefficient A: 1
Enter the coefficient B: 2
Enter the coefficient C: -8
Solutions are: 2.0 and -4.0
Enter the coefficient A: 1
Enter the coefficient B: -12
Enter the coefficient C: 36
Solutions are: 9.0 and 3.0
Enter the coefficient A: 2
Enter the coefficient B: 9
Enter the coefficient C: -5
Solutions are: -0.75 and -3.75
Enter the coefficient A: 4
Enter the coefficient B: 6
Enter the coefficient C: 20
Solutions are: 0.0 and -1.5
Enter the coefficient A: 0
Enter the coefficient B: 0
Enter the coefficient C: 0
Program ended.
```

I am expecting the following roots with the inputs above:

```
Run1: 2, -4

Run2: 6

Run3: .5, -5

Run4: 'Equation has two complex roots.'
```

When I run the program, the output is wrong for the last 3 times the program runs, and seems to be setting the discriminant equal to values greater than 0, when I expect it to change the output based off the discriminant calculated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are your input number are integers only or decimals

Comment: '...in all the inputs I have tried. ' - Please give some sample input and the output you obtain vs the expected one.

Comment: How wrong are your numbers? What numbers did you try?

Comment: All input is integers. I have used: a=1,b=2,c=-8, and a=1,b=-12, and c=36

Comment: Please add your expected values, your gotten values and hardcode them to make this a [mcve]

Comment: Alright, I added my output code.

Comment: As well as my expected outputs.

Comment: I fixed the parentheses and got one correct output out of the four. But it still is not using my if statement correctly, and always runs as if the discriminant is greater than 0. I updated my code with the revised parentheses, as well as my new output code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. My discriminant function was outside of the while statement, so when the 3 variables were entered from the user, it was keeping the first discriminant calculated in each loop, which was why the output was producing 2 answers each run. By changing the position of the discriminant function to inside of the while statement, it now recalculates the discriminant for each loop for the while statement. This is the correct code for this problem:

```
import math
import Disc

def main():



    coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))

    while coeffA != 0:

        coeffB = int(input('Enter the coefficient B: '))
        coeffC = int(input('Enter the coefficient C: '))

        disc = Disc.discriminant(coeffA, coeffB, coeffC)

        if disc > 0:

            solutionOne = (-coeffB + math.sqrt(disc)) / (2 * coeffA)
            solutionTwo = (-coeffB - math.sqrt(disc)) / (2 * coeffA)

            print('Solutions are: ' + str(solutionOne) + ' and ' + str(solutionTwo))

            coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))

        elif disc == 0:

            solutionOne = -coeffB / (2 * coeffA)

            print('Solution is: ' + str(solutionOne))

            coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))

        elif disc < 0:

            print('Equation has two complex roots.')

            coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))

    print('Program ended.')


    # End of the main function
```

The correct output code produced is the following:

```
Enter the coefficient A: 1
Enter the coefficient B: 2
Enter the coefficient C: -8
Solutions are: 2.0 and -4.0
Enter the coefficient A: 1
Enter the coefficient B: -12
Enter the coefficient C: 36
Solution is: 6.0
Enter the coefficient A: 2
Enter the coefficient B: 9
Enter the coefficient C: -5
Solutions are: 0.5 and -5.0
Enter the coefficient A: 4
Enter the coefficient B: 6
Enter the coefficient C: 20
Equation has two complex roots.
Enter the coefficient A: 0
Program ended.
```

Thank you for all the help and advice from the Stack Overflow community!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a pair of brackets.
This should fix the errors:

```py
if disc > 0:

            solutionOne = (-coeffB + math.sqrt(disc)) / (2 * coeffA)
            solutionTwo = (-coeffB - math.sqrt(disc)) / (2 * coeffA)

            print('Solutions are: ' + str(solutionOne) + ' and ' + str(solutionTwo))

            coeffA = int(input('Enter the coefficient A: '))
            coeffB = int(input('Enter the coefficient B: '))
            coeffC = int(input('Enter the coefficient C: '))
```